# Is it possible to run the Terrafrom/Ansible scripts without having them on a running EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ansible, terraform, amazon-sns

**Background**:

We have several legacy applications that are running in AWS EC2 instances while we develop a new suite of applications. Our company updates their approved AMI's on a monthly basis, and requires all running instances to run the new AMI's. This forces us to regularly tear down the instances and rebuild them with the new AMI's. In order to comply with these requirements all infrastructure and application deployment must be fully automated.

**Approach**:

To achieve automation, I'm using Terraform to build the infrastructure and Ansible to deploy the applications. Terraform will create EC2 Instances, Security Groups, SSH Keys, Load Balancers, Route 53 records, and an Inventory file to be used by Ansible which includes the IP addresses of the created Instances. Ansible will then deploy the legacy applications to the hosts supplied by the Inventory file. I have a shell script to execute the first the Terrafrom script and then the Ansible playbooks.

**Question**:

To achieve full automation I need to run this process whenever an AMI is updated. The current AMI release is stored in Parameter store and Terraform can detect when there is a change, but I still need to manually trigger the job. We also have an AWS SNS topic to which I can subscribe to receive notification of new AMI releases. My initial thought was to simply put the Terraform/Ansible scripts on an EC2 instance and have a Cron job run them monthly. This would likely work, but I wonder if it is the best approach.  For starters, I would need to use an EC2 instance which itself would need to be updated with new AMI's, so unless I have another process to do this I would need to do it manually. Second, although our AMI's could potentially be updated monthly, sometimes they are not. Therefore, I would sometimes be running the jobs unnecessarily. Of course I could simply somehow detect if the the AMI ID has changed and run the job accordingly, but it seems like a better approach would be to react to the AWS SNS topic.

Is it possible to run the Terrafrom/Ansible scripts without having them on a running EC2 instance? And how can I trigger the scripts in response to the SNS topic?

Comment: Are you already aware of [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx#readme), which supports programmatic triggering of [Job Templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.5.3/html/userguide/job_templates.html#launch-a-job-template)?

Comment: Beyond that, you'll also want to narrow your question, and also include any steps you have already tried but that did not work, as right now your question is overly broad as well as running the risk of being closed for being opinion based, since there are many, many, *many* ways of doing what you've asked, each with tradeoffs

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel, we use Ansible Tower on prem, but it too runs on a server, and if moved to AWS, it would also be subject to monthly redeploys to make sure that it runs the latest golden company approved ami. It seems like I cant  fully automate this prcess without some form of manual intervention. Perhaps I could run the scripts from a scheduled Lamda function?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel, so far we have tried with Terraform/Ansible, which works, but we are running the scripts from a EC2 instance. This EC2  instance also needs to be torn down and redeployed to update the AMI. Which I need to do manually on a monthly basis

Comment: Store the scripts on S3, have a Lambda function that runs once a month that spins up an EC2 instance with the latest AMI, passing it a user-data script which downloads the scripts from S3 onto the new EC2 server and runs them, waits for the scripts to finish, then terminates the EC2 instance. You could probably build something much more elaborate using the AWS SSM service, which has some support for Ansible.

Comment: You can use AWS Codebuild service with docker image and you can integrate your codebuild trigger with SNS or scheduled. In this case, you don't need to worry about having an Ec2 and managing it.

Answer (score 0):

options i was testing to trigger ansible playbook in response to webhooks from alertmanager to have some form of self healing ( might be useful for you)

1. run ansible in aws lambda and have it frontend with api gaetway as webhook .. alertmanager trigger -> https://medium.com/@jacoelho/ansible-in-aws-lambda-980bb8b5791b
2. SNS receiver in AWS -> susbscriber-> AWS system manager - which supports ansible :

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/keeping-ansible-effortless-with-aws-systems-manager/

3. Alertmanager target jenkins webhook -> jenkins pipline uses ansible plugin to execute playbooks :

https://medium.com/appgambit/ansible-playbook-with-jenkins-pipeline-2846d4442a31

4. frontend ansible server with a webhook server which execute ansible commands as post actions
   this can be flask based webserver or this git webhook provided below :

https://rubyfaby.medium.com/auto-remediation-with-prometheus-alert-manager-and-ansible-e4d7bdbb6abf

https://github.com/adnanh/webhook

5. you can also use AWX ( ansible tower in opensource form) which expose ansible server as a api endpoint ( webhook) - currently only webhooks supported - github and gitlab.